# iOS Line Graphing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

What would be the easiest way to graph a line graph on a iOS app? I am building a iOS app that needs a line graph I don't need anything complex just something that will graph a int.

I have seen core graph but not sure if thats the way to go.

Comment: What do you need?  Axes lines, axes names, axes units?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably thinking of [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), which would be a fine solution if you want something that has a lot of features and is ready out of the box.

If you want something more minimal, you could create your own line graph UIView subclass very easily and make it do exactly what you want. Building a general-purpose graph library is a lot of work because there are so many ways that people like to vary their graphs. If you know exactly what you want and don't need something more flexible, rolling your own can be a quick and effective solution.

If you do decide to roll your own, Matt Gallagher's [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/) blog has a number of very good [graphics entries](http://cocoawithlove.com/search/label/CoreGraphics) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Accelerometer sample app (on their [iOS Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) web site) includes some example code for a simple line graph.

Answer (score 1):

Nuclios http://www.infragistics.com/products/ios/ is a pre-built library that has a bunch of graphing styles. It's not free but I don't think the license fee is outrageous either ~$250

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [BEMSimpleLineGraph](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph).

It's modeled after UITableView and offers a wide range of features.